# How to get jooq record on list

Tags: java, jooq

I have a method

```java
private List<User> selectUser() {
    return dslContext
        .select(USER_ACCOUNT.asterisk())
        .from(USER_ACCOUNT)
        .fetch(recordMapper);
}
```

How do I get the data into the list?

```java
public User getUser(String userId) {
    return selectUser()
            .where(USER_ACCOUNT.USER_ACCOUNT_ID.eq(userId))
            .fetchOne(recordMapper);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to read `UserAccountRecord` instead of `User` POJO values? Then just use [`DSLContext.selectFrom()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#selectFrom(org.jooq.Table)). E.g.

```java
private List<UserAccountRecord > selectUser() {
    return dslContext
        .selectFrom(USER_ACCOUNT)
        .fetch();
}

public UserAccountRecord getUser(String userId) {
    return selectFrom(USER_ACCOUNT)
            .where(USER_ACCOUNT.USER_ACCOUNT_ID.eq(userId))
            .fetchOne();
}
```